# LAN cable not connected, but it is

Tags: windows-xp, router, ethernet, lan

I have a Windows XP SP2 desktop PC. It connects to the internet with a LAN cable (there's a wireless router for my laptop in between). The problem should be software because:

- when i tried connecting the same LAN cable to my laptop it works
- when i plugin the LAN cable (onboard) the green light is on and the orange light flickers
- when i tried the other cable (that feeds the wireless router) i have the same problem
- it worked a few days ago, nothing specific changed

I tried removing the ethernet card from the device manager, and windows automatically reinstalled it.

What could cause this? What can I try?

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

- Checking that `ipconfig /all` shows MAC & other info. If not suspect HW.
- Using XP's Network Manager to diagnose the problem
- booting from a [live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) to see if it sees the LAN

Comment: I tried this. MAC is ok. I installed Network Monitor (is that the one you mean? otherwise more info please). If I get it right it sends a request to the DHCP server (to obtain an IP i guess) but I don't see a response returning. Also, I cannot startup msconfig. Any ideas?

Comment: Also I'm not sure whether my DHCP server should be on the wifi router or on the computer itself...

Comment: I meant XP's built-in [network repair](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/maintain/repair.mspx) tool. There's also a [Diagnostic tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914440) you can download. Normally your router provides DHCP service.

Comment: I tried that and the log says: status of the network adapter is not good. I guess if the light still indicates green it would work or could the hardware still be broken? I'll try the live CD now...

Answer (score 0):

When your PC can connect by both wireless *and* wires it can get very confused.

First: ensure that you're not connected to any wireless network.

Then: you can diagnose your Ethernet base-T cable issues.